# Is Endor still available for salvage droids?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Endor has not turned up among the locations available for my salvage droids to retrieve salvage from in about three weeks. Is this some really bizarre coincidence or is it really no longer available?

I want some more Ewoks. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely. I have just unlocked shoda and deej yesterday. I have not seen kashyyyk in 2 weeks though

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Update from the OP, converted from a comment:</sub>

---

It appeared, after four weeks, eventually. I seriously thought I was missing something; and since I cannot access the store from where I am, I tend to get impatient.